# Do we have to generate Angular Web Workers in a separate file?

Tags: javascript, angular, multithreading, typescript, web-worker

The [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker) says to do this:

```
ng generate web-worker location
```

And that works great.  Just curious whether we have to generate the worker in a separate file or can we just create one a service:

```
const worker = new Worker()
worker.addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  const response = `worker response to ${data}`;
  postMessage(response);
});
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not due to angular, it is due to [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) itself: yes, you are forced to use a separate file.

Hope this helps.